# Hide Plank on KDE startup, but keep on Gnome?

Tags: gnome, kde, startup, plank

I'm trying out new desktop environments, and just downloaded KDE. I like having Plank on Gnome, but would like to disable it on startup for KDE. How do you start Plank on one desktop environment, but disable startup of Plank on another?

Comment: Ok, tried the suggestions in that post a few times with no success only to realize I had to close plank on KDE or it will just reopen it on launch since it was open before. Had to run the command "pkill plank" in KDE and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, see KDE's  *Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Desktop Session > On Login*. You can make choices here for "applications to be excluded …"